# rasa_nlu Failed building wheel for spacy and Failed building wheel for thinc

Tags: spacy, rasa-nlu

conda 4.5.8

Python 3.6.0

Operating system: Win10

According to the rasa_core installation documentation, I have successfully installed rasa_core(pip install rasa_core) and rasa_nlu(pip install rasa_nlu[tensorflow]), of course I also encountered during the installation process. To the problem of Failed building wheel for twisted, I downloaded the installation file corresponding to my operating system and python at https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#twisted: Twisted‐18.7 .0‐cp36‐cp36m‐win_amd64.whl is saved to my machine and successfully installed using cmd into the directory where the .whl file  is located (pip install Twisted‐18.7.0‐cp36‐cp36m‐win_amd64.whl).

However, now when I install spacy using pip install rasa_nlu[spacy], I get the following error message:

(rasa) D:\rasa>pip install rasa_nlu[spacy]
Requirement already satisfied: rasa_nlu[spacy] in d:\anaconda3\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (0.12.3)

Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13 in d:\anaconda3\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa_nlu[spacy]) (1.15.0)

Requirement already satisfied: six in d:\anaconda3\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa_nlu[spacy]) (1.11.0)

Requirement already satisfied: simplejson in d:\anaconda3\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa_nlu[spacy]) (3.16.0)

Requirement already satisfied: pathlib in d:\anaconda3\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa_nlu[spacy]) (1.0.1)

Requirement already satisfied: packaging in d:\anaconda3\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa_nlu[spacy]) (17.1)

Requirement already satisfied: typing in d:\anaconda3\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa_nlu[spacy]) (3.6.4)

Requirement already satisfied: tqdm in d:\anaconda3\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa_nlu[spacy]) (4.24.0)

Requirement already satisfied: jsonschema in d:\anaconda3\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa_nlu[spacy]) (2.6.0)

Requirement already satisfied: klein in d:\anaconda3\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa_nlu[spacy]) (17.10.0)

Requirement already satisfied: cloudpickle in d:\anaconda3\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa_nlu[spacy]) (0.5.3)

Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in d:\anaconda3\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa_nlu[spacy]) (2.2.2)

Requirement already satisfied: requests in d:\anaconda3\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa_nlu[spacy]) (2.19.1)

Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in d:\anaconda3\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa_nlu[spacy]) (3.13)

Requirement already satisfied: boto3 in d:\anaconda3\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa_nlu[spacy]) (1.7.65)

Requirement already satisfied: future in d:\anaconda3\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa_nlu[spacy]) (0.16.0)

Requirement already satisfied: gevent in d:\anaconda3\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa_nlu[spacy]) (1.3.5)

Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn; extra == "spacy" in d:\anaconda3\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa_nlu[spacy]) (0.19.2)

Requirement already satisfied: sklearn-crfsuite; extra == "spacy" in d:\anaconda3\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa_nlu[spacy]) (0.3.6)

Collecting spacy>2.0; extra == "spacy" (from rasa_nlu[spacy])

Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/24/de/ac14cd453c98656d6738a5669f96a4ac7f668493d5e6b78227ac933c5fd4/spacy-2.0.12.tar.gz

Requirement already satisfied: scipy; extra == "spacy" in d:\anaconda3\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from rasa_nlu[spacy]) (1.1.0)

Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.0.2 in d:\anaconda3\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from packaging->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (2.2.0)

Requirement already satisfied: werkzeug in d:\anaconda3\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from klein->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (0.14.1)

Requirement already satisfied: Twisted>=15.5 in d:\anaconda3\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from klein->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (18.7.0)

Requirement already satisfied: incremental in d:\anaconda3\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from klein->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (17.5.0)

Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in d:\anaconda3\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (1.0.1)

Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in d:\anaconda3\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (0.10.0)

Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in d:\anaconda3\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (2.7.3)

Requirement already satisfied: pytz in d:\anaconda3\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (2018.5)

Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in d:\anaconda3\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from requests->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (2018.4.16)

Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in d:\anaconda3\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from requests->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (3.0.4)

Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.24,>=1.21.1 in d:\anaconda3\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from requests->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (1.23)

Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.8,>=2.5 in d:\anaconda3\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from requests->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (2.7)

Requirement already satisfied: botocore<1.11.0,>=1.10.65 in d:\anaconda3\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from boto3->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (1.10.65)

Requirement already satisfied: jmespath<1.0.0,>=0.7.1 in d:\anaconda3\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from boto3->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (0.9.3)

Requirement already satisfied: s3transfer<0.2.0,>=0.1.10 in d:\anaconda3\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from boto3->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (0.1.13)

Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.11.5; sys_platform == "win32" and platform_python_implementation == "CPython" in d:\anaconda3\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from gevent->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (1.11.5)

Requirement already satisfied: greenlet>=0.4.13; platform_python_implementation == "CPython" in d:\anaconda3\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from gevent->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (0.4.14)

Requirement already satisfied: tabulate in d:\anaconda3\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from sklearn-crfsuite; extra == "spacy"->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (0.8.2)

Requirement already satisfied: python-crfsuite>=0.8.3 in d:\anaconda3\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from sklearn-crfsuite; extra == "spacy"->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (0.9.5)

Requirement already satisfied: murmurhash<0.29,>=0.28 in d:\anaconda3\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from spacy>2.0; extra == "spacy"->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (0.28.0)

Requirement already satisfied: cymem<1.32,>=1.30 in d:\anaconda3\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from spacy>2.0; extra == "spacy"->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (1.31.2)

Requirement already satisfied: preshed<2.0.0,>=1.0.0 in d:\anaconda3\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from spacy>2.0; extra == "spacy"->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (1.0.0)

Collecting thinc<6.11.0,>=6.10.3 (from spacy>2.0; extra == "spacy"->rasa_nlu[spacy])

Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/94/b1/47a88072d0a38b3594c0a638a62f9ef7c742b8b8a87f7b105f7ed720b14b/thinc-6.10.3.tar.gz

Requirement already satisfied: plac<1.0.0,>=0.9.6 in d:\anaconda3\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from spacy>2.0; extra == "spacy"->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (0.9.6)

Requirement already satisfied: ujson>=1.35 in d:\anaconda3\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from spacy>2.0; extra == "spacy"->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (1.35)

Requirement already satisfied: dill<0.3,>=0.2 in d:\anaconda3\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from spacy>2.0; extra == "spacy"->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (0.2.8.2)

Collecting regex==2017.4.5 (from spacy>2.0; extra == "spacy"->rasa_nlu[spacy])

Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ad/0b/c1c5781a707e6ea01bcf57d8ad3c42125260fca67ef79206ecaef04a8754/regex-2017.04.05-cp36-none-win_amd64.whl

Requirement already satisfied: PyHamcrest>=1.9.0 in d:\anaconda3\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from Twisted>=15.5->klein->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (1.9.0)

Requirement already satisfied: Automat>=0.3.0 in d:\anaconda3\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from Twisted>=15.5->klein->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (0.7.0)

Requirement already satisfied: hyperlink>=17.1.1 in d:\anaconda3\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from Twisted>=15.5->klein->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (18.0.0)

Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.4.0 in d:\anaconda3\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from Twisted>=15.5->klein->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (18.1.0)

Requirement already satisfied: zope.interface>=4.4.2 in d:\anaconda3\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from Twisted>=15.5->klein->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (4.5.0)

Requirement already satisfied: constantly>=15.1 in d:\anaconda3\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from Twisted>=15.5->klein->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (15.1.0)

Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in d:\anaconda3\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from kiwisolver>=1.0.1->matplotlib->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (40.0.0)

Requirement already satisfied: docutils>=0.10 in d:\anaconda3\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from botocore<1.11.0,>=1.10.65->boto3->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (0.14)

Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in d:\anaconda3\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from cffi>=1.11.5; sys_platform == "win32" and platform_python_implementation == "CPython"->gevent->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (2.18)

Requirement already satisfied: msgpack<1.0.0,>=0.5.6 in d:\anaconda3\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from thinc<6.11.0,>=6.10.3->spacy>2.0; extra == "spacy"->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (0.5.6)

Requirement already satisfied: msgpack-numpy<1.0.0,>=0.4.1 in d:\anaconda3\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from thinc<6.11.0,>=6.10.3->spacy>2.0; extra == "spacy"->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (0.4.3.1)

Requirement already satisfied: cytoolz<0.10,>=0.9.0 in d:\anaconda3\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from thinc<6.11.0,>=6.10.3->spacy>2.0; extra == "spacy"->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (0.9.0.1)

Requirement already satisfied: wrapt<1.11.0,>=1.10.0 in d:\anaconda3\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from thinc<6.11.0,>=6.10.3->spacy>2.0; extra == "spacy"->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (1.10.11)

Requirement already satisfied: pyreadline>=1.7.1 in d:\anaconda3\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from dill<0.3,>=0.2->spacy>2.0; extra == "spacy"->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (2.1)

Requirement already satisfied: toolz>=0.8.0 in d:\anaconda3\envs\rasa\lib\site-packages (from cytoolz<0.10,>=0.9.0->thinc<6.11.0,>=6.10.3->spacy>2.0; extra == "spacy"->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (0.9.0)

Building wheels for collected packages: spacy, thinc

Running setup.py bdist_wheel for spacy ... error

Complete output from command D:\Anaconda3\envs\rasa\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\spark\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vv2q80rk\spacy\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\spark\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-qduotc_g --python-tag cp36:

running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py

creating build
  ...
  copying spacy\tests\tokenizer\sun.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\spacy\tests\tokenizer
  running build_ext

building 'spacy.parts_of_speech' extension

error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

---

Failed building wheel for spacy

Running setup.py clean for spacy

Running setup.py bdist_wheel for thinc ... error

Complete output from command D:\Anaconda3\envs\rasa\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\spark\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vv2q80rk\thinc\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\spark\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-xtskfjxp --python-tag cp36:

Warning: The nvcc binary could not be located in your $PATH. For GPU capability, either add it to your path, or set $CUDA_HOME

running bdist_wheel

running build
  running build_py
  ...
  copying thinc\extra\search.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\thinc\extra

running build_ext

building 'thinc.linalg' extension

error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

---

Failed building wheel for thinc

Running setup.py clean for thinc

Failed to build spacy thinc

Installing collected packages: thinc, regex, spacy

Found existing installation: thinc 6.10.2

```
Uninstalling thinc-6.10.2:

  Successfully uninstalled thinc-6.10.2
```

Running setup.py install for thinc ... error

```
omplete output from command D:\Anaconda3\envs\rasa\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\spark\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-vv2q80rk\\thinc\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\spark\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-1tufq2pm\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:

Warning: The nvcc binary could not be located in your $PATH. For GPU capability, either add it to your path, or set $CUDA_HOME

running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext

building 'thinc.linalg' extension

error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

--------------------------------------
```

Rolling back uninstall of thinc

Command "D:\Anaconda3\envs\rasa\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\spark\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vv2q80rk\thinc\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\spark\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-1tufq2pm\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\spark\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vv2q80rk\thinc\

I tried to solve the problem by install theincc-6.10.3.tar.gz and spacy-2.0.12.tar.gz  but I was failed, I got a similar error as above.

Answer (score 1):

From the error messages printed it seems that you need to install *Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools*

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools
```

I would start there. If that still doesn't work I would also suggest:

- Installing with a tool like [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/#macos)
- Installing with [Docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/rasa/rasa_nlu/)

Lastly I would recommend editing your question to put the entire console messages in a code block.